# Regex: How to match sequence of SAME characters?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match "any consecutive chains of SAME character that is NOT .(period) "

Lets say I have

```
line = '....xooo......'
```

If I do this,

```
match in re.findall(r'[^\.]{2,}', line)
```

match returns "xooo".

Instead, I only want "ooo," which is a sequence of SAME character..

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
line = '....xooo......aaaa...'
import re
print [whole for whole, _ in re.findall("(([^.])\\2+)", line)]
```

**Output**

```
['ooo', 'aaaa']
```

`([^.])` matches anything but `.` and it is captured as a group. `\\2` refers to the inner captured group which is the character matched by `([^.])` and `+` means atleast once. So, it matches `ooo`

Comment: Hm yeah this works! but I was looking for something shorter.. I thought there was a way to do this is in a single line :( Do you think this is impossible?

Comment: why do you need double parenthesis? You can just do "([^.])\1+", right?

Comment: @user2492270 Do not complain about length! :) The pattern you are trying to match, although it constitutes a regular set, requires a very long regular expression, if we stick to true regular expressions; basically a large union of individual patterns which individually match things like `aaaaaa...` and `bbbbb...`.  The backreference feature allows for non-regular sets to be matched; i.e. to get it as brief as the above, we had to leave behind the domain of regular expressions already, and you want it shorter. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
re.search(r'(([^.])\2{1,})', line).group(1)
```

Explanation:

```
"(([^.])\2{1,})"
    1st Capturing group (([^.])\2{1,})
    2nd Capturing group ([^.])
      Negated char class [^.] matches any character except:
         . The character .
    \2 1 to infinite times [greedy] Matches text saved in the 2nd capturing group
```

If you want all the matches of that constraint:

```
>>> line = '....xooo...xx..yyyyy.'
>>> map(lambda t: t[0], re.findall(r"(([^.])\2+)", line))
# ['ooo', 'xx', 'yyyyy']
```

Comment: Try now -- Perl to Python issue :-0